# How to configure quartz job to run on terracotta cluster?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, terracotta

I am trying to configure our quartz job in Tomcat to run on terracotta cluster. Spring terracotta prop config looks like this

```
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.terracotta.quartz.TerracottaJobStore</prop>
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tcConfigUrl">localhost:9510</prop>
```

Terracotta server is running.

When I start Tomcat instance I am getting following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.terracotta.collections.LockStrategy
```

I can't find this class any where, neither in quartz-terracotta jar, or terracotta toolkit jar.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Terracotta are you using?

A [quick Google search suggests](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-terracotta/2.1.0/ehcache-terracotta-2.1.0-javadoc.jar?folder=org/terracotta/collections/) the class is in `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:2.1.0` - I'm not sure about later versions. If it's not in the current version of the terracotta jar you are using, you might want to double-check that you aren't using incompatible versions of the various libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that one, It says in docs but when you include the 2.1.0 jar, it contains no LockStrategy class.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in your toolkit-runtime jar. Are you saying this is not in there ? Can you provide more info ? Like versions and stacktrace ?